# Metro app set startup object - page

Tags: microsoft-metro

How would I set a different startup page ?
the current page \ form is GroupedItemsPage
I want to change this to testpage ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the default start page for your application by editing the package manifest that is in the root of your project.

1. Expand the node for your project
2. Double click `package.appxmanifest`
3. Select the start page option, and point it to the file you want.

Comment: I dont see the "start page" option. There are 4 available tabs: Application UI, Capabilities, Declarations, and Packaging. None of them has the "start page" option.

Comment: It's under Application UI, second text box down, immediately after "Display Name"

Answer (score 0):

In XAML-C#, There is no "start page" option on the package.appxmanifest. So the answer above does not work.

in App.xaml.cs, add the following:

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    ...
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(YourCustomStartupPage), "AllGroups");
}
```